# Simple RNN example showing numerics

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to understand RNNs and I would like to find a simple example that actually shows the one hot vectors and the numerical operations. Preferably conceptual since actual code may make it even more confusing. Most examples I google just show boxes with loops coming out of them and its really difficult to understand what exactly is going on. In the rare case where they do show the vectors its still difficult to see how they are getting the values.

for example I don't know where the values are coming from in this picture https://i1.wp.com/karpathy.github.io/assets/rnn/charseq.jpeg

If the example could integrate LSTMs and other popular extensions that would be cool too.

Answer (score 2):

In the simple RNN case, a network accepts an input sequence **x** and produces an output sequence **y** while a hidden sequence **h** stores the network's dynamic state, such that at timestep i: x(i) ∊ ℝ<sup>M</sup>, h(i) ∊ ℝ<sup>N</sup>, y(i) ∊ ℝ<sup>P</sup> the real valued vectors of M/N/P dimensions corresponding to input, hidden and output values respectively. The RNN changes its state and omits output based on the state equations:

1. h(t) = tanh(W<sub>xh</sub> ∗ [x(t); h(t-1)]), where W<sub>xh</sub> a linear map: ℝ<sup>M+N</sup> ↦ ℝ<sup>N</sup>, * the matrix multiplication and ; the concatenation operation. Concretely, to obtain h(t) you concatenate x(t) with h(t-1), you apply matrix multiplication between W<sub>xh</sub> (of shape (M+N, N)) and the concatenated  vector (of shape M+N) , and you use a tanh non-linearity on each element of the resulting vector (of shape N).
2. y(t) = sigmoid(W<sub>hy</sub> * h(t)), where W<sub>hy</sub> a linear map: ℝ<sup>N</sup> ↦ ℝ<sup>P</sup>. Concretely, you apply matrix multiplication between W<sub>hy</sub> (of shape (N, P)) and h(t) (of shape N) to obtain a P-dimensional output vector, on which the sigmoid function is applied.

In other words, obtaining the output at time t requires iterating through the above equations for i=0,1,...,t. Therefore, the hidden state acts as a finite memory for the system, allowing for context-dependent computation (i.e. h(t) fully depends on both the history of the computation and the current input, and so does y(t)).

In the case of gated RNNs (GRU or LSTM), the state equations get somewhat harder to follow, due to the gating mechanisms which essentially allow selection between the input and the memory, but the core concept remains the same.

---

**Numeric Example**

Let's follow your example; we have M = 4, N = 3, P = 4, so W<sub>xh</sub> is of shape (7, 3) and W<sub>hy</sub> of shape (3, 4). We of course do not know the values of either W matrix, so we cannot reproduce the same results; we can still follow the process though.

- At timestep t<0, we have h(t) = [0, 0, 0].
- At timestep t=0, we receive input x(0) = [1, 0, 0, 0]. Concatenating x(0) with h(0<sup>-</sup>), we get [x(t); h(t-1)] = [1, 0, 0 ..., 0] (let's call this vector u to ease notation). We apply u * W<sub>xh</sub> (i.e. multiplying a 7-dimensional vector with a 7 by 3 matrix) and get a vector v = [v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>3</sub>], where v<sub>i</sub> = Σ<sub>j</sub> u<sub>j</sub> W<sub>ji</sub> = u<sub>1</sub> W<sub>1i</sub> + u<sub>2</sub> W<sub>2i</sub> + ... + u<sub>7</sub> W<sub>7i</sub>. Finally, we apply tanh on v, obtaining h(0) = [tanh(v<sub>1</sub>), tanh(v<sub>2</sub>), tanh(v<sub>3</sub>)] = [0.3, -0.1, 0.9]. From h(0) we can also get y(0) via the same process; multiply h(0) with W<sub>hy</sub> (i.e. 3 dimensional vector with a 3 by 4 matrix), get a vector s = [s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub>, s<sub>3</sub>, s<sub>4</sub>], apply sigmoid on s and get σ(s) = y(0).
- At timestep t=1, we receive input x(1) = [0, 1, 0, 0]. We concatenate x(1) with h(0) to get a new u = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0.3, -0.1, 0.9]. u is again multiplied with W<sub>xh</sub>, and tanh is again applied on the result, giving us h(1) = [1, 0.3, 1]. Similarly, h(1) is multiplied by W<sub>hy</sub>, giving us a new s vector on which we apply the sigmoid to obtain σ(s) = y(1).
- This process continues until the input sequence finishes, ending the computation.

*Note: I have ignored bias terms in the above equations because they do not affect the core concept and they make notation impossible to follow*

Comment: thanks, can you put this or show me an example of a visual form with as simple a network as possible? Can you tell me how they got those numbers in the link I posted?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly how they got these particular numbers, as I don't know the weights W and the solution is not unique, but I can make up something similar. I'll do so first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: Added a rough overview of the example you uploaded.